fopen(...): Failed to open stream: Permission denied
I am using laravel 10 (just for API) and vue. The web application is running on a IIS server.
I am getting an error quite often:
production.ERROR: fopen(D:\Projects\TestProject\storage\framework/cache/data/e9/7d/e97d811f085318637cdcda703b63e4dc6269d1c3): 
Failed to open stream: Permission denied {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): fopen(D:\\Projects\\TestProject\\storage\\framework/cache/data/e9/7d/e97d811f085318637cdcda703b63e4dc6269d1c3): 
Failed to open stream: Permission denied at D:\\Projects\\TestProject\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Filesystem\\LockableFile.php:69)

I don't know how to fix it...
I gave storage/framework/cache/data folder full permissions for the IUSR group and IIS_IUSRS (my_domain\IIS_IUSRS) but nothing... still getting the error.
Anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Have you tried giving the permissions to the TestProject folder rather than just the storage/framework/cache/data folder? I tend to run sudo chown -R :developers <folder> and sudo chmod -R 775 <folder> and it seems to do the trick

Please check both Laravel logs in storage/logs and the IIS logs in C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles for any additional information that might help pinpoint the issue.

I don't see any errors in the IIS log, @Tehcheatah I used that on linux server and is ok, but not on IIS :( I was thinking that i could do that by right click on data folder and on security tab set for "Everyone" -> "Read & execute"

It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

iis use the application pool for access sources(file , memory, ...)
you set user in application pool with user administrator or user then access your projects

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
